# FLUTTER - show all markers maps from list json API

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

anyone please help me for displaying markers maps from list json on flutter google maps.

> i dont know this is right way or not for displaying markers from list json. my markers on map not showing

**My services API**

```
Future<List<UnitModel>> getUnit() async {
    var url = 'myprivateurl';
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('$url/unit'), headers: {'api-key': 'privateapi'});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      List<dynamic> data = jsonData["data"];
      setState(() {
        listLatLngUnit = data;
        return listLatLngUnit;
      });
    }
    print(listLatLngUnit);
  }
```

**and my code**

```
  List<UnitModel> listLatLngUnit = [];
```

```
         Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 300,
                child: GoogleMap(
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
                    _controller.complete(controller);

                  },
                  markers: listLatLngUnit.map((latLong) => Marker(markerId: MarkerId(latLong.unitLat.toString()),
                      position: LatLng((latLong.unitLat),
                          (latLong.unitLong)))).toSet(),
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: const LatLng(-6.009756, 106.046373),
                    // target: _center,
                    // target: const  LatLng(0,0),
                    zoom: 11.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: What is your question here? Do you have any errors?

Comment: sorry, i was edited the question. can you understand what i mean?. and please help me

Comment: This [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter) could help you. Have you checked this already?

Comment: not yet..
but the error was fixed ><
thanks for answer Mr. Nelson